# Execute GenericFilterBean only on response with Spring boot 2.0.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I have seen that if I register a Spring `GenericFilterBean` class, it invoked every time on request. Is it possible to invoke another filter (maybe another `GeneircFilterBean`) only when service is returning the response? Basically, I wanted to achieve the same behavior as `Jersey` `ContainerResponseFilter`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can pass you code after  chain.doFilter(request, response) method.
Here is example.

```
public class SimpleLoggingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
//This code will work after response
        if ((response instanceof HttpServletResponse) && (request instanceof HttpServletRequest))  {           
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            System.out.println("Response status is " + httpServletResponse.getStatus() +" " +
                    "Response  content-length is " + httpServletResponse.getHeader("content-length"));
        }
    }
}
```